# Failed to build cardano-crypto-wrapper

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, cabal

When I run "cabal build all" I get the error message "Failed to build cardano-crypto-wrapper-1.5.1.0". See below for log file. Any assistance would be appreciated. I was so close to the end!

```
Failed to build cardano-crypto-wrapper-1.5.1.0.
Build log (
/Users/larry/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.10.7/crdn-crypt-wrppr-1.5.1.0-ac1a8b90.log
):
Warning: cardano-crypto-wrapper.cabal:129:31: colon specifier is experimental
feature (issue #5660)
Configuring library for cardano-crypto-wrapper-1.5.1.0..
Preprocessing library for cardano-crypto-wrapper-1.5.1.0..
Building library for cardano-crypto-wrapper-1.5.1.0..
[ 1 of 22] Compiling Cardano.Crypto.Orphans ( src/Cardano/Crypto/Orphans.hs, dist/build/Cardano/Crypto/Orphans.o, dist/build/Cardano/Crypto/Orphans.dyn_o )
[ 2 of 22] Compiling Cardano.Crypto.ProtocolMagic ( src/Cardano/Crypto/ProtocolMagic.hs, dist/build/Cardano/Crypto/ProtocolMagic.o, dist/build/Cardano/Crypto/ProtocolMagic.dyn_o )
[ 3 of 22] Compiling Cardano.Crypto.Random ( src/Cardano/Crypto/Random.hs, dist/build/Cardano/Crypto/Random.o, dist/build/Cardano/Crypto/Random.dyn_o )
[ 4 of 22] Compiling Cardano.Crypto.Raw ( src/Cardano/Crypto/Raw.hs, dist/build/Cardano/Crypto/Raw.o, dist/build/Cardano/Crypto/Raw.dyn_o )
[ 5 of 22] Compiling Cardano.Crypto.Hashing ( src/Cardano/Crypto/Hashing.hs, dist/build/Cardano/Crypto/Hashing.o, dist/build/Cardano/Crypto/Hashing.dyn_o )
[ 6 of 22] Compiling Cardano.Crypto.Signing.Redeem.VerificationKey ( src/Cardano/Crypto/Signing/Redeem/VerificationKey.hs, dist/build/Cardano/Crypto/Signing/Redeem/VerificationKey.o, dist/build/Cardano/Crypto/Signing/Redeem/VerificationKey.dyn_o )
<command line>: dlopen(/Users/larry/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.7/lib/libHScrdn-crypt-prs-2.1.2.0-5a34eb6e-ghc8.10.7.dylib, 0x0005): symbol not found in flat namespace (_crypto_vrf_ietfdraft03_bytes)
cabal: Failed to build cardano-crypto-wrapper-1.5.1.0 (which is required by
test:tx-generator-test from tx-generator-2.5, test:tx-generator-apitest from
tx-generator-2.5 and others). See the build log above for details.
```

Comment: What are the contents of `/Users/larry/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.10.7/crdn-crypt-wrppr-1.5.1.0-ac1a8b90.log`.
Also what versions of ghc and cabal are you using?

Comment: The contents of that file are in my post. cabal-install version 3.6.2.0 and The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.7

Answer (score 2):

This is due to use of old forked libsodium dependency. Follow the updated [install guide](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/) to ensure your`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env var points to the correct build.

If you're using nix, then unset `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` because it can override the shared object used by nix for the correct libsodium.

Comment: I updated the shell profile and get the same error. small-steps-test-1.0.0.0 also fails to build for the same reason.  export PATH=$PATH:/Users/larry/Library/Python/3.9/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
[ -f "/Users/larry/.ghcup/env" ] && source "/Users/larry/.ghcup/env" # ghcup-env

Comment: Can somebody please elaborate and provide more details on James' answer. I am completely new to Cardano but learning. And although I am computer engineer I'm not a full time developer but I can understand and problem solve with a few more details. Thanks.